# Imagens no html ou via css

Tags: html5, css3

Existe alguma vantagem em carregar uma imagem via css com: `background: url ('imagem.jpg');` ao invés de usá-la normalmente como: `<img src="imagem.jpg">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejo duas questões principais a serem levadas em consideração:

#### Semântica e Acessibilidade

O uso da tag `<img>`, por meio do atributo `alt`, gera uma interpretação do buscadores, o que influencia no SEO da página, de acordo com seus algoritmos.

Além disso, alguns leitores de página para deficientes visuais analisam as imagens baseadas também nesse atributo, o que não acontece com o uso da imagem como background no CSS.

#### Padrões

No uso de símbolos em uma biblioteca de padrões, por exemplo, é muito mais proveitoso o uso de backgrounds, já que basta aplicar uma classe ou algo do tipo, para que dentro do elemento tenha a imagem desejada, seja esta um ícone ou um símbolo.

Answer (score 3):

Uma vantagem que vejo é que por CSS o código se torna reaproveitável. Caso várias tags *img* usem o mesmo estilo e for necessário alterar o caminho da imagem, bastaria alterar o estilo que é aplicado para todos. Direto no elemento teria que ser alterado um por um.